# Install VirtualBox on Ubuntu 12.04.1 (on [Samsung] Chromebook)

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04, chromebook

I have dual booted Ubuntu Linux 12.04.1 LTS on my Samsung Series 5 ChromeBook, and am trying to run/install Oracle VirtualBox (from the *generic .run file* downloaded from their website). However, every time I try to run it (as root from the command line), it gives me the following error occurs:

```
Please install the build and header files for your current Linux kernel.
The current kernel version is 3.4.0
Problems were found which would prevent VirtualBox from installing.
```

I have tried the version from the Software Center, as well as the command line installation, both of which gave me errors based on my `linux-headers/linux-kernel/linux-[kernel]-image`.

Here's an error I keep getting (on the command line):

```
First Installation: checking all kernels...
It is likely that 3.4.0 belongs to a chroot's host
Building only for 3.5.0-18-generic
Building initial module for 3.5.0-18-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.5.0-18-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.5.0-18-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/make.log for more information.
Setting up virtualbox-qt (4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

...And one of the more cryptic errors I get when trying to start any Virtual Machine:

```
Result Code:      NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component:        Machine
Interface:        IMachine {5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91}
```

Comment: Isn't VirtualBox in the Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: in the cloud???

Comment: Yes, but I've tried that already...and it gave me an error similar to the one above.

Comment: Try to type this before: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: I have (and just did) try, but to no avail :(

Comment: Is your ubuntu up to date? (`sudo apt-get update`and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`)

Comment: also...when I run `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`, it tells me that my headers are already the most recent version, but virtualbox still fails

Answer (score 0):

Do these links help you? try to start with those...

- [Cannot install virtualbox addition inside a linux guest system](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/cannot-install-virtualbox-addition-inside-a-linux-guest-system-694066/)
- [Why do I get this error installing virtualbox-4.1 on Arch?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17740/why-do-i-get-this-error-installing-virtualbox-4-1-on-arch)
- [Fedora 11 - please install GNU compiler](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=21543&start=0)

Comment: let me check...

Comment: no...unfortunately they didn't because they apply to fedora, while I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 (12.04.1, technically speaking)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg : Yes, I agree, that would be quite helpful

Answer (score 0):

I found these links very helpful:

**This is probably the best one (or atleast the one that has produced the most promising results so far):**  **https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild**

**Here are two others that were somewhat helpful:**
A Discussion in Google Groups:
**https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/chromebook-central/PPQFpC7mYzk/yW2hfNd7OHUJ**

and
A Blog post: **http://compilethekernel.blogspot.com/2011/08/compile-linux-kernel.html**

*Good Luck and Happy Compiling!!!*
-iphonedev7